# <rich:placeholder> with jsf 2.0 and richfaces 3.0.0 doesn't work

Tags: jsf-2, xhtml, richfaces

I am looking for a solution which can help me to use `<rich:placeholder>` in jsf2.0 and richfaces 3.0.0

Do you have any proposals?

The error message:

```
<rich:placeholder> Tag Library supports namespace: http://richfaces.org/rich, but no tag was defined for name: placeholder
```

Comment: Your version of richfaces doesn't support it. What version of JSF2 are you running? 2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<rich:placeholder>` was added to RichFaces in 4.3 version, if you want to use it you'll have to update. (Which you should do anyway, RF 3.0.0 is very, very old)

Comment: i can't because my company works with that and i can't change it

Comment: Then you can not use it, you should try another solution. If it is not important to support old browsers, just add this javascript code : document.getElementById("yourelement").placeholder = "....";